# Should the service in an MVC app return entities or list of entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've a MVC application with Spring and Hibernate

I've each controller calling the service layer that call the dao

```
controller > service > dao
```

Should the service always return an entities?

I was trying to move the logic from the controller to the service. At the moment this is the logic in the controller

```
autenticate

retrieve user information (service call)

retrieve his appointments (other service call)

create a status response in xml

return appointemnts
```

As you can see if I move all the logic in the service I would need a service call that return an xml instead of a user or a list of appointemts.

Is this the right way or I should keep the logic in the controller and return from the service only entities?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, I think that is immaterial to you.  What you must remember is

- To keep your service layer clean of data access implementations (for example: an `import java.sql.whatever` would be a bad idea inside your service layer)
- The service layer is the ideal place to put your declarative transaction management in.  The idea is to write transactional service layer methods, and under that, have a totally naive DAO layer that will have their connections injected, their errors managed outside, no commits, no rollbacks...

Your idea of moving the logic out of your controller layer is perfectly sound.  Your concern about the XML is legitimate, but, whatever your service layer returns, always remember that the format is a matter for the presentation layer.  Your service layer (and ideally the controller too) should be completely unaware of the format that will be rendered for the user.  This is the way to have a proper service layer that is reusable across the many presentation layers you could devise for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Good question but hard to answer.

I'll try to help you find the answer that is correct for you:

What does the Service abstract over?

What does the Controller abstract over?

One possible set of answers is:

The Controller abstracts over the access mechanisms (xml, http, ...)

The Service abstracts over the business logic (beware the oxymoron) like: Who can see what appointments

The Daos abstract over the fact where stuff is stored. Appointments get retrieved the same way from Daos although one might come from an LDAP System and the other from a relational Database.

If these happen to be your answers you should move retrieval of user information and retrieval of appointments and user authentication to the service and rendering as xml stays in the Controller.

But it is really up to you and your team how you need to slice and dice the application.

One experiment that helps me to come up with reasonable answers is to think about other clients. What if a different application want this information. What would they access, how should the API look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, the service should not always return an entity (or list of entities).

It hard say without the actual code, but sometimes the following approach works better:

```
controller > facade > service > dao
```

The facade provides for your controller a method to create an appointment and returns xml back. At the same time, the service stays cleaner and let's say returns the user entity only

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Answer (score 0):

**No,** a service can return everything you want. There is no limit to what it provides for you. Even a DAO or repository does not have to return entities perse. They just need to return whatever you want from the database.

That said, with Spring **there are preferred ways** to handle certain tasks. For instance the XML you want to return from the service can be generated by message converters. All you need to do is ask for XML in the request and return the object or `ResponseEntity <T>` from the handler annotated with `@ResponseBody`.

Move and keep as much logic out of the controller as you can. Controllers that do a lot of the work are hard to test. This also applies to services by the way. It's better to split everything into little easy to manage pieces instead of having a large unit of work in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I would not return xml from the service layer. Think about code reuse. What if that service will be needed later on other services. What will be of more use to you a list of users presented in an xml or a list of user objects. What if later on you need to present an users json? The controller should massage the data into a presentable format. At least that's my opinion.